# Micro Frontend : Pubsub system for micro front end

Tags: angular, vue.js, web-component, publish-subscribe, micro-frontend

I am creating a large application by following ***micro front end architecture***. 
Let say, I have divided my entire application into 5 Micro Apps **(micro-app-A(in Vue),micro-app-B(in Vue),micro-app-C (in Angular) , micro-app-D (in React) and a shell Application My-App-Shell (in Vue))**

I have used **pubsub-js** library **(a topic-based publish/subscribe library written in JavaScript**) to communicate **between different components within a micro-app**. My each micro app is perfectly using  this pubsub system to communicate between its **own components**. But i need a common pubsub system (managed by my shell appliaction) to communicate between **different micro apps**.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Dispatching `CustomEvent`s from window object may be an option.

Comment: yes this is one of the way, but i want to use topic based pubsub here

Comment: It's a matter of abstraction. Your pubsub service subscribe for all events. Keeps and internal list of topic subscriptions and fire then when event target matches.

Comment: hmm..sounds good, thanks

Comment: Why not use pubsub-js for the same purpose?

Comment: it is not seems possible (i tried it earlier) because here event needs to be send to another application not within the application

Comment: You could use dependency injection and inject the global pubsub during initialisation?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily build an abstraction on top of `CustomEvent` here:

```js
const handlers = {};

window.publish = (topic, message) => {
  var ev = new CustomEvent('pubsub', {
    detail: { topic, message },
  });
  document.body.dispatchEvent(ev);
};

window.subscribe = (topic, handler) => {
  const topicHandlers = handlers[topic] || [];
  topicHandlers.push(handler);
  handlers[topic] = topicHandlers;
};

window.unsubscribe = (topic, handler) => {
  const topicHandlers = handlers[topic] || [];
  const index = topicHandlers.indexOf(handler);
  index >= 0 && topicHandlers.splice(index, 1);
};

document.body.addEventListener('pubsub', ev => {
  const { topic, message } = ev.detail;
  const topicHandlers = handlers[topic] || [];
  topicHandlers.forEach(handler => handler(message));
});
```

(For a demo see: https://jsfiddle.net/qo5nca71/)

In most cases this should be sufficient. If you want to get more "safety" (e.g., that microfrontends cannot change the abstractions, which are in the impl. above just globally available) I would suggest using a more sophisticated approach like the eventing mechanism in Piral (see https://github.com/smapiot/piral).